# Raster clipping outside area in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, clip, erase

How to raster clip in ArcMap? But I need 1 raster in outside area. Because 2 raster map.

Example:

```
Ras1=Temperature.tif
Ras2=Error map.tif
Clip command input raster=Ras1
             Output Extent= Ras2
```

Just I need clip outside area=reserve clip command? I can't use Con and Setnull, IsNull.

[image]

Comment: You're trying to erase Ras2 from Ras1 is that right? You don't have access to spatial analyst license? How do you feel about using GDAL? or QGIS?

Comment: Yes, Can I make this process in ArcMap? I don't know GDAL and QGIS. If you give me help and user guide in GDAL and QGIS. I have access to spatial anaylyst license.

Comment: So you *can* use SetNull, Con, IsNull. The best you can hope for is to set the result raster to Null in the area where Ras2 is not null. That shouldn't be too difficult if Ras2 is null where it is shown as white, use IsNull to get 0/1 raster for Ras2 and then con(IsNull(Ras2),OutNull,Ras1) where OutNull is the Null value for result raster, if one is not set then pick a value outside of range and then use SetRasterProperties to enforce that value on Result Raster.

Comment: Thank you very much, perfectly working. I'm trying to do SetNull. But just Conditional tool-Con command. I'm very glad to you.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I think you should transfer your comment into an answer, unless you have come across an earlier duplicate.

Comment: I agree @PolyGeo, I'm a bit busy at the moment. Ganaa, feel free to answer your own question using the comment and your own experience, if you have not done so by the time I check again I will make it an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by @MichaelStimson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152677/how-to-raster-clip-in-outside-in-arcmap/250585#comment224391_152677):

> you can use SetNull, Con, IsNull. The best you can hope for is to set
>   the result raster to Null in the area where Ras2 is not null. That
>   shouldn't be too difficult if Ras2 is null where it is shown as white,
>   use IsNull to get 0/1 raster for Ras2 and then
>   con(IsNull(Ras2),OutNull,Ras1) where OutNull is the Null value for
>   result raster, if one is not set then pick a value outside of range
>   and then use SetRasterProperties to enforce that value on Result
>   Raster.